# 2 static ip addresses, 2 routers, 1 modem

Tags: networking

Since internet access of both routers is thru 1 modem do the subnets need to be different on the two modems? For example can both routers use 192.168.1.1/24 or does one need to use 192.168.2.1/24 or 192.168.0.1/24? 
I would like to stay with 1 modem, 1 ISP and 1 static IP address and split the users into 2 subnets with an additional router. The user pool is around 235. To avoid changing all static IP's I would like to have both subnets be 192.168.1.1.  My goal is to have 510 available user IP's instead of 254.

Comment: It would really help us a lot if you told us what you were trying to do and what Windows 7 had to do with anything. (We either need to know what effect you are trying to get or how the routers are connected.)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily - You can use one router as a 'simple' switch - either by using DHCP forwarding, or just turning off DHCP. You can alternately use a double nat - with router 2 having an ip address on router 1, and giving out ip addresses from router 2.

Both options work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each router is NAT,  has its own static WAN IP and is hooked to the modem, the LAN side of each router is independent and can use the same private ranges... Although I use separate subnets to make identification easier...